# Creating a dict from a set of variables using their names

Tags: python

I have a few variables from which I want to create a dictionary. This is done in a loop, and will later be used for a list of such dictionaries, for example to create a `pandas.DataFrame`. 
For example,

```
res = []
for item in my_collection:
    foo = foo_function(item)
    bar = bar_funtion(item)
    baz = baz_function(item)
    res.append(dict(foo=foo, bar=bar, baz=baz))
```

What I'm asking is in fact how to create the dictionary more succinctly, by only providing the variable names.
something like `make_dict(foo,bar,baz)`

Comment: So if I get this you'd like to have a list of dicts where one dict looks like: { "foo": foo, "bar": bar ...}?

Comment: @pasha yes, you got it.